# Como imprimir todas las paginas en mi aplicación web

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, quasar, ts

Tengo una solución realizada en typescript y vue, y necesito realizar una impresión de una tabla, sin embargo cuando realizo esta acción y son demasiados registros, al imprimir la prebvisualización me corta las páginas y no agrega todo el contenido, este es mi codigo:

```
 mounted() {
    window.print();
    window.onafterprint = () => {
      this.redirect();
    };
    window.onclose = () => {
      this.redirect();
    };
    this.redirect();
  },
```

y así es como esta el resultado actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="contenido-a-imprimir">
    <Reporte :datatabla="proptabla">
      <template v-slot:filtros>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="q-ml-sm " v-if="filters.linea != ''">
            <label class="label" style="font-weight: bold">Linea:</label
            ><label class="valor q-ml-sm">{{
              filters.linea
            }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="q-ml-sm "  v-if="filters.material != ''">
            <label class="label" style="font-weight: bold">Material:</label
            ><label class="valor q-ml-sm">{{
              filters.material
            }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="q-ml-sm fechaDesde">
            <label class="label" style="font-weight: bold">Fecha desde:</label
            ><label class="valor q-ml-sm">{{
              filters.dateFilters.desde
            }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="q-ml-sm fechaHasta">
            <label class="label" style="font-weight: bold">Fecha hasta:</label
            ><label class="valor q-ml-sm">{{
              filters.dateFilters.hasta
            }}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </Reporte>
  </div>
</template>
```

y esta son las reglas de estilos:

```
@media print {
  //

  #contenido-a-imprimir, #contenido-a-imprimir * {
      visibility: visible;
  }

  @page {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    size: landscape;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


  #drawer__menu, #drawer__menu__header, #drawer__menu__footer{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .q-page {
    min-height: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    

  }

  .q-page-container {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
  }

  .printreport {
    .q-table {
      &__container {
         
        // box-shadow: none !important;
      }

      tr, th {
        font-size: 10px;

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: puedes probar colocar esa tabla dentro de un Div, y luego imprimir el contenido del mismo.

Comment: tengo mi contenido dentro de un div y sigue ocurriendo, no sé qué puede ser, editaré im pregunta para mostrar el archivo vue

Comment: Es un tema bien interesante, lectura sugerida: https://sympli.io/blog/a-quick-guide-to-css-for-printable-webpages Saludos.